# if i am upgarding framework 2.0 to 4.0 then framwork 2.0 project should work or not

Tags: asp.net, .net, frameworks

Currently i'm working on framework 2.0 web application, if i'm upgarding framework 2.0 to 4.0 then framework 2.0 web application should work or not..

Comment: The possible duplicate is because at first I understand that you ask if the existing 2 version that have been updating on 4. If the question is the existing 2 versions without updating on 4, yes they will stay and still work on 2. - The ver 4 and ver 2 exist together and have different install directories.

Answer (score 0):

The application will work correctly if upgrading from .net 2.0 to 4.0 note that when rebuilding the project some methods may be marked as either depreciated or obsolete and will suggest using the newer version of that method and a pointer to it. Consider changing those flagged methods.